# Trying to delete entries from SQLite db in Visual Studio 2015, c#, Universal Windows App, no errors, but not deletes

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, win-universal-app

I can't seem to delete entries from my ListView which binds the database. I can see everything in the database, and have added checkboxes and it doesn't matter how I select it... it won't delete the entry. I'm going nuts, I've tried everything I can find. So here's my listview code

Okay, and update. When I put in

```
var existingconact = conn2.Query<Medications>("select * from Medications where Id = 4").FirstOrDefault();
```

I click the button and it deletes it and updates the table. So I'm doing something wrong with the Id.

```
 <StackPanel Margin="20, 240, 0 0">
            <ListView Header="Medications" x:Name="myList" Background="DimGray" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="600">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Width="600">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <CheckBox  HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="CheckBoxItem"/>

                        <TextBlock x:Name="Id" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Id}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />

                        <TextBlock x:Name="medName" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding MedName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" x:Name="medDose" Text="{Binding MedDose}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" x:Name="whatFor" Text="{Binding WhatFor}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />


                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </StackPanel>
```

Here is the button command I'm using to try and delete the entry

```
   private void btn_Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {



        DBPath2 = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "meds.sqlite");
        using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn2 = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath2))

        {
            var existingconact = conn2.Query<Medications>("select * from Medications where Id = ?").FirstOrDefault();
            if (existingconact != null)
            {
                conn2.RunInTransaction(() =>
                {
                    conn2.Delete(existingconact);
                });
```

And if you want to take a look, my schema

```
 public class Medications
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string MedName { get; set; }
        public string MedDose { get; set; }
        public string WhatFor { get; set; }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it! It was one little line in Meds.xaml.cs

This is the button that is handling the click.

```
private void btn_Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        DBPath2 = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "meds.sqlite");
        using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn2 = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath2))

        {
// **This as where the error was**
            var existingconact = conn2.Query<Medications>("select * from Medications where **Id = Id"**).FirstOrDefault();
            if (existingconact != null)
            {
                conn2.RunInTransaction(() =>
                   {
                       conn2.Delete(existingconact);
                   });
                myList.ItemsSource = conn2.Table<Medications>();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You never passed in the ID to find the SQLite record.  This line:

```
var existingconact = conn2.Query<Medications>("select * from Medications where Id = ?").FirstOrDefault();
```

Needs to pass in the value of Id:

```
var existingconact = conn2
    .Query<Medications>(
                "select * from Medications where Id = ?", 
                 myList.SelectedItem.Id)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now, getting the ID from the selected row is what you need to handle.  You might have to cast the `myList.SelectedItem` to your expected data type to compile.

You can validate this by retrying your hard coded test into the parameterized one:

```
var existingconact = conn2.Query<Medications>("select * from Medications where Id = ?", 4).FirstOrDefault();
```